# How to get output stream for Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand command?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run the below command

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $instance.ResourceGroupName -Name $instance.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Users\tushar.raichand\Desktop\sample.ps1'
```

Sample.ps1 is as below

```
$output = Get-LocalUser
Write-Output $output
$output
```

The output i am getting for Invoke-AzVMRunCommand is

```
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.Models.PSRunCommandResult
```

Comment: what if you do `gm -inputObject $output`?

Comment: $output = Get-LocalUser
gm -inputObject $output
Write-Output $output

Tried this not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have enough permission to show the details of a command, see [**Limiting access to Run Command**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#limiting-access-to-run-command):

> Listing the run commands or showing the details of a command require the `Microsoft.Compute/locations/runCommands/read` permission, which the built-in [Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) role and higher have.

Besides, the command `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand` belongs to the `AzureRM` powershell module which has been deprecated, you may need to upgrade it to the new `Az` module, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.6.0#upgrade-to-az) to upgrade.

I test the script with the new `Az` command [`Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell), it works fine.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -Name joyVM -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\sample.ps1'
```

*sample.ps1*:

```
$output = Get-LocalUser
Write-Output $output
```

*Result*:

[image]

Comment: I have made some changes to original question please have a look.

Comment: @TusharRaichand For the original question, could you get the details of the output successfully now?

Comment: Yes i getting the result of Invoke-AzVMRunCommand command when i run it in console, but not when i am running it in a powershell script. As mentioned above.

Comment: @TusharRaichand They are totally two different questions, my reply solved your original question. I think you need to modify your question back and accept it as the answer, then post a new question. Then I could look into it, stackoverflow avoid to ask several different questios in the same post.

Comment: Okay let me close this question and open a new one.

Comment: @TusharRaichand Add a Note in your new question like: This post is different from xxx post to let others know they are in different environments, then it will not be duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471733/invoke-azurermvmruncommand-command-displaying-wrong-output-when-run-in-powershel

Comment: I have created a new post.. please help... Have a look at above URL