# How to read text in .txt file and each of its value in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-powershell

I have data in a text file like below, i want to read it value by value using powershell

```
Name           Enabled Description                                             
----           ------- -----------                                             
administrator1 True                                                            
Azureuser      True    Built-in account for administering the computer/domain  
DefaultAccount False   A user account managed by the system.                   
Guest          False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain
```

For example i want to read value for name in 2nd field. How can it be read?

Comment: This seems to be the textual table output from a collection of PSObjects. It is not meant for saving to text file and parsing that. Use the objects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to convert it without having a delimiter in place. With a delimiter you could make use of [ConvertFrom-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1)

If we would use ConvertFrom-String with this format, it will parse the first 2 columns correctly, but the description will be seperated in words.

```
((Get-Content .\test.txt) | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames Name, Enabled)
```

Result:

```
Name           Enabled P3          P4
----           ------- --          --
Name           Enabled Description
----           ------- -----------
administrator1 True
Azureuser      True    Built-in    account
DefaultAccount False   A           user
Guest          False   Built-in    account
```

To get the second result you have to take in account the header and separator line.
This will return the full object.

```
((Get-Content .\test.txt) | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames Name, Enabled)[3]
```

Result:

```
Name    : Azureuser
Enabled : True
P3      : Built-in
P4      : account
P5      : for
P6      : administering
P7      : the
P8      : computer/domain
```

This will only return the value from "Enabled"

```
(((Get-Content .\test.txt) | ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames Name, Enabled)[3]).Enabled
```

Result:

```
True
```

Comment: I want to delete these 2 rows from result Name           Enabled Description
----           ------- -----------. How will that be possible?

Comment: So how can I get the value for `Description`?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing that kind of format is not easy, but here is an attempt:

```
$lineNo = 0
Get-Content .\test.txt | foreach {
    # if first line, make a regex for parsing based on the headers
    # (assumes header names have no spaces)
    if ($lineNo -eq 0) {
        $matches = [regex]::Matches($_, '\w+ +')
        $headers = $matches | foreach {$_.Value.Trim()}
        # build a regex based on column names & lengths
        $regex = $(for($i = 0; $i -lt $matches.Count; $i++) {
            if ($i -lt $matches.Count - 1) {
                $quantifier = "{" + $matches[$i].Length + "}"
            } else { $quantifier = "+" }
            "(?<$($headers[$i])>.$quantifier)"
        }) -join ""
    }
    # skip 2nd line and parse all others with the regex created before
    elseif ($lineNo -gt 1) {
        if ($_ -match $regex) {
            [pscustomobject]$matches | select $headers
        }
    }
    $lineNo++
# Now you can easily get the value you want
} | select Name
```

This will work properly for all 3 columns. Even with spaces in the values.
(The script will break, if there are spaces in the header names, but this is usually not the case.)

Answer (score 1):

Best transform the text into an object with properties again.

This is quite easy as the 1st two columns don't have spaces in the values,
so this one liner:

```
gc .\file.txt|?{$_ -notmatch '^[ -]+$'}|%{$_.trim(' ') -split ' +',3 -join ','}|convertfrom-csv
```

yields this output:

```
Name           Enabled Description
----           ------- -----------
administrator1 True
Azureuser      True    Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
DefaultAccount False   A user account managed by the system.
Guest          False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain
```

Looks familiar?

Yes, but stored in a variable i.e. $Data = ...,
allows you to directly acsess the 2nd Name (index is zero based) with

```
> $Data[1].Name
Azureuser

> $Data[2].Description
A user account managed by the system.
```

To better explain what the script does, here a dealiased version:

```
$Data = Get-Content .\file.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '^[ -]+$'} |
  ForEach-Object{
   $_.trim(' ') -split ' +',3 -join ','
  } | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

`Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '^[ -]+$'}` removes the line with only dashes and spaces

`$_.trim(' ')` removes the trrailing spaces from the lines

`-split ' +',3` splits the line at any number of spaces >1 into exactly 3 pieces

which are stuck together with `-join ','` forming a valid csv file with a header

The final `| ConvertFrom-Csv` does the work.

Comment: I like this solution! Very slim, and works for the given example +1 But unfortunately breaks easily, the simplest cases being a space in the name or a comma in the description for instance.

Answer (score 0):

> For example i want to read value for name in 2nd field. How can it be read?

If I do not misunderstand, you want to read `Azureuser` in the txt file, try the command below, `$txt[3].Split()[0]` is what you want.

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\users.txt'
$txt[3].Split()[0]
```

[image]