# why is powershell not printing txts with line breaks?

Tags: powershell, txt

so i am trying to display commands for a powershell script for self-use. i am using a txt file as the source of the list. the txt file is formatted as so;

```
command (* is input)| description
----------------------------------------------------
pack                | opens folder pack
c * / cpp *         | copies mingw command to compile 
code                | reveals source
copy *              | copies input
```

Now; i have a function called that prints out this txt file and the function is this;

```
Function help{
 Write-Host (get-content -path {file-path})
  }
```

However, in the terminal, the output looks like this;

```
command (* is input)| description ----------------------------------------------------  pack           | opens folder pack * / cpp *                        | copies mingw command to compile  code
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use `Write-Host` to output *data* - it is meant for *display* output.

  - `Write-Host` *stringifies* the array that `Get-Content` outputs, which means space-concatenating its elements, hence the single-line display.
- Use `Write-Output` to output data or, better yet, rely on PowerShell's *implicit* output feature:

```
Function help {
  # Get-Content's output is implicitly output.
  Get-Content -path somefile.ext
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) for more information.