# How get output to a variable

Tags: powershell, output

I have a simple powershell script

```
$proc = Get-Process -id 412
$proc
```

it's return such output

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                                                                                
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                                                                                                
    434      26    65768     109144       6,42    412   1 browser
```

how can i get this output to a variable so i can use it somewhere else in script?

I tryed to use it likes this

```
$proc = Get-Process -id 412
Write-Host $proc
```

but it gives me not same output as $proc is a instance of "System.Diagnostics.Process" class

```
System.Diagnostics.Process (browser)
```

Comment: If your goal is just to write process object to host, you could write `$proc | Out-Host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean.  $proc is an object with properties.  If you do `$x = $proc | out-string` then `$x` will be the string representation of the default view.  However in terms of using it later you might like to do `write-host $proc.Handles $proc.NPM $proc.PM $proc.WS $proc.CPU $proc.id $proc.SI $proc.ProcessName` to access each of the individual elements.

Answer (score 3):

**[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)**, whose purpose is to write directly to the *display*, **does *not* use PowerShell's rich output formatting system** - it **uses simple `.ToString()` formatting** instead, which often results in unhelpful representations - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) for details.

If you explicitly want to **print to the display (host) *only* while using *rich formatting*, use

[`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) instead**:

```
$proc | Out-Host # rich formatting, display output only
```

<sup>The [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) cmdlet uses the same formatting and returns the formatted representation as *data*, in the form of a single, multi-line string
(by default).</sup>

However, if there's no concern about accidentally producing *data* output, via PowerShell's *success output stream* (see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection)), **you can simply use PowerShell's *implicit output* behavior, which also results in rich formatting** if the data is ultimately sent to the display (in the absence of getting captured in a variable, sent through the pipeline, or getting redirected):

```
# Implicit output to the success stream, which, if not captured or redirected,
# prints to the display *by default*, richly formatted.
$proc
```

The above is the implicit - and generally preferable - equivalent of `Write-Output $proc`; explicit use of [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), whose purpose is to write to the *success output stream*, is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution that give me same output result

```
$proc = Get-Process -id 412
$str = Out-String -InputObject $proc
Write-Host $str
```