# PowerShell If statement not equating properly

Tags: powershell, if-statement

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Why do the 2 variables not equal each other?

When I run this script

```
$temp1 = "@{Dhcp=Disabled}"
$temp2 = Get-NetIPInterface My_Ethernet | select Dhcp
write-host ""
write-host "1" $temp1
write-host "2" $temp2
write-host ""
if ($temp2 -eq $temp1){
    write-host "IP address is Static "
}
Else {
    write-host "IP address is Not Static"
}
```

**I get this result**

```
1 @{Dhcp=Disabled}
2 @{Dhcp=Disabled}
    
IP address is Not Static
```

Comment: You're comparing 2 objects, the references are compared, not the content

Comment: Objects are compared _by identity_, not equivalence. Since `$temp1` and `$temp2` contain 2 distinct objects, the comparison fails. Do `$temp1.Dhcp -eq $temp2.Dhcp` instead

Answer (score 1):

With the helpful suggestion from Mathias this is now working as expected

```
$temp1 = "Disabled"
$temp2 = Get-NetIPInterface My_Ethernet | select Dhcp
write-host ""
write-host ""
write-host "1" $temp1
write-host "2" $temp2.dhcp
write-host ""
write-host ""
if ($temp2.dhcp -eq $temp1){
    write-host "IP address is Static "
}
Else {
    write-host "IP address is Not Static"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement [your own effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373907/45375):

Since your intent was to compare a property's *value* to another value,  `select -ExpandProperty Dhcp` would have returned that value directly (see the docs for [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)):

```bash
if ((Get-NetIPInterface My_Ethernet | select -ExpandProperty Dhcp) -eq $temp1) { # ...
```

However, it would be much simpler to use direct property access, using `.`, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-):

```bash
if ((Get-NetIPInterface My_Ethernet).Dhcp -eq $temp1) { # ...
```

Note that `.Dhcp` would work even if your `Get-NetIPInterface` call returned *multiple* objects, in which case an *array* of values is returned, courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).<sup>[1]</sup>

Finally, note that [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is [typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g. `$value`, instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).

To explicitly print only to the display *but with rich formatting*, use [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host), given that the `.ToString()` stringification that `Write-Host` uses on its input is often unhelpful - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66035767/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Note that PowerShell's comparison operators such as `-eq` exhibit *filtering* behavior when their LHS is an array (collection); that is, instead of returning `$true` or `$false`, they then return the *sub-array of matching elements* - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).</sup>