# Powershell - Fix Line Break

Tags: powershell

I have a situation here and I would like to share it with you to ask for help.

I have a TXT file that I receive every day and I need to import it into my ERP, however, this file comes with a line break that we have to manually adjust
[image: img1]

And when adjusted, it looks like this:
[image: img2]

```
{
    Write-Error "Informe um arquivo para leitura"
    Return
}

$arquivo = $args[0]

if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($arquivo)) 
{
    Write-Error "Arquivo nao encontrado: $arquivo"
    Return
}

$tamanhoEsperado = 240
$ultimoTamanho = 0

foreach($linha in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($arquivo))
{
    if ($linha.length -gt 0)
    {
        if (!($linha.length -eq $tamanhoEsperado) -And (($linha.length + $ultimoTamanho) -eq $tamanhoEsperado))
        {
            Write-Host -NoNewLine $linha
            $ultimoTamanho += $linha.length
        }
        else
        {
            if ($ultimoTamanho -gt 0) 
            {
                Write-Host
            }
            Write-Host -NoNewLine $linha
            $ultimoTamanho = $linha.length
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        Write-Host
    }
}
```

But I am not able to make the process automatic with this script.

Powershell will look for the TXT file in a specific folder, validate if the file has 240 positions and if not, correct that line break shown in img1. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) for more information.
- Therefore, your code only produced *for-display* output, not *data*.

---

Try something like the following:

```
$fragment = ''
$correctedLines = 
  foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($arquivo)) {
    if ($fragment) {    # The previous line was incomplete.
      $fragment + $line # Concatenate the fragment with the current line and output.
      $fragment = ''    # Reset the fragment variable.
    } elseif ($line.Length -ne 240) {
      $fragment = $line # Save the fragment and continue.
    } else {
      $line             # Complete line -> output it.
    }
  }
```

Note the use of *implicit* output (e.g., `$line`) and that you can directly collect all output from the `foreach` statement in a variable.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand how to apply this to my code. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @LucasAlexandreVieiradeAlme, `$correctedLines` is the array of repaired lines, which you can send to a file with `$correctedLines | SetContent ...`,  for instance.  If you don't want to collect the corrected lines in memory first, enclose the entire `foreach` statement in `& { ... }` and pipe that to `Set-Content`. I don't know if my loop body implements all the logic you need (the Portuguese variable names didn't help), but you should be able to adapt it easily.