# Returning system array then using it Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, function

I have the following function that gets a list of folder names and displays the results in
a tabular fashion. Once that is done, I want to iterate through that list to do different
things depending on the situation. Thus, the need to have a function so I don't have to repeat the code for every situation. The function:

```
Function Show-UsersFolders{

   # Get list of folders where file is to be copied
   $listOfFolders = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object Name

   # Display total folders and display them in tabular form (8 columns)
   Write-Host ("`nFound: " + $listOfFolders.Count + " users folders.")
   $listOfFolders | Format-Wide -Column 8

   , $listOfFolders

}

$myList = Show-UsersFolders

ForEach ($folder in $myList) {

  Write-Host $folder

}
```

I get the following:

[image]

If I just call the funcion, nothing else (no ForEach loop afterwards), I get:

[image]

How do I go about printing the results and returning them so I can iterate through them later?
I've read about how Powershell returns "everything", but I can't just make sense out of it so I can work with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your misconception is that the `Format-*` cmdlets actually display something in the console. They don't. All they do is _prepare_ data for formatted output, which you see as `FormatStartData` and so on in the console. To separate these from the actual output of the function, you may do it like this: `Write-Host ($listOfFolders | Format-Wide -Column 8 | Out-String)`

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right you don't actually need a function in such a case. It should be enough to save the output of `Get-ChildItem` in a variable like this:

```
$UserFolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users' -Directory
```

Now you can do all sorts of actions with the folder list ... like outputting the count of the elements ...

```
$UserFolderList.Count
```

... or like outputting only a few selcted properties of the folders in the folder list ...

```
$UserFolderList | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, FullName
```

... or even running further actions on each individual folder in the folder list ...

```
foreach ($UserFolder in $UserFolderList) {
    "Name of the folder: '$($UserFolder.name)' - full path of the folder: '$($UserFolder)'"
}
```

And because you did not limit yourself to a particular property with a `Select-Object` in the first place you can still access all the properties a folder has ... and you can do this again and again with the variable. ;-)

```
$UserFolderList | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, LastAccessTime
```

and of course you can still format the output as you like ...

```
$UserFolderList | 
    Select-Object -Property Name |
        Format-Wide
```

Answer (score 0):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, even though the purpose of `Format-*` cmdlets is to format objects *for display*, their output - in the form of objects providing *formatting instructions* - is still sent to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) (which is the stream whose output is sent through the pipeline, captured in a variable, or redirected with `>`) rather than directly to the *host* (display).

You can use the [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) cmdlet to *explicitly* request that those processing instructions be interpreted and rendered *to the host* - as they would be by default - *independently of the success output stream*.

- By contrast, when [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) renders objects to the host (display), it performs simple `.ToString()` rendering, which with complex objects typically results in *unhelpful* representations - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) for more information.

You can combine `Out-Host` with the [common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) in order to *both*:

- *print* a command's output objects' formatted representation to the host (display) via `Out-Host`
- and *also capture* the output objects as-is in a target variable, via `-OutVariable`

```bash
# * Prints a formatted representation of the .Name property values,
#   via Format-Wide and Out-Host, directly to the host (display).
# * Also captures the command output in variable $listOfFolders, via
#   the common -OutVariable parameter. Note that the target variable,
#   $listOfFolders, must be specified WITHOUT "$"
Get-ChildItem -Directory -OutVariable listOfFolders |
  Format-Wide -Column 8 -Property Name |
  Out-Host

# $listOfFolders now contains an array [list] of [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
# instances, which you can process as needed.
```